# ReactJS: Nested .map with conditional expression to match values

Tags: arrays, reactjs, loops, nested

I have two arrays
this.state.race
{
  "raceName": "President",
  "raceID": 100
}

this.state.candidates (for example)
{
  "canName": "John",
  "canID": 1,
  "raceID": 100
},
{
  "canName": "David",
  "canID": 2,
  "raceID": 100
},
{
  "canName": "Sally",
  "canID": 3,
  "raceID": 101
}

i want to show all the races and only the candidates that have a matching raceid

so it would be like this:

Race 100:
  1. John
  2. David
Race 101:
  {empty list}

my code is this:

```
render() {
  return (
    {this.state.racelist.map(myrace => (
       {myrace.title}
       <divider />
       {this.state.candidatelist.map(mycand => (
          {/********************************************************
          how can i put a conditional statment here that checks to see if,
          mycand.raceID === myrace.raceID  ???? and if those match, render
          mycand info
          ********************************************************/}
       ))}
    ))}
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. return null

`list.map(item => if(condition) item else null)`

2. use filter

`list.filter(condition).map(renderItem)`